# How to Fix Getting CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct error

Tags: virtual, void, protected

How to Fix Getting CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct error

```
{       ImplementsSystem.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging;
        ImplementsSystem.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;


        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging();
        }

        {

        if (((this.PropertyChangingEvent == null) == false)) {
                if (PropertyChanging != null) {
                    RaiseEventPropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);    

                }
            }
        } 


        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName) {
        if (((this;PropertyChangedEvent == null) 
                    == false)) {
            RaiseEventPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i will hive a chocolate who answered it first

Comment: What do you mean by this `ImplementsSystem.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging;
        ImplementsSystem.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;`

Comment: I'll have a chocolate while you fix the syntax errors and add a tag to indicate thr language this is in. But without being rude, please take the [tour] and visit [ask] because in general we don't do *fix my code* questions, specially if it lacks where the error is, isn't properly formatted and is sprinkeld with syntax errors. With a little bit more effort from your side someone might be better able to help you and future visitors that stumble on your question.